# Constraints vs. Restraints

Tags: grammar

I know that in English there is a difference between these words, but since I'm a Portuguese native speaker and we have just one word for that (that would be 'restrições') it'd be good to ask: do you, in your routine, use them interchangeably? Or the difference just pops up dealing with scientific articles and researches?

Comment: What did the dictionary say?  Please add some research you've done yourself.

Comment: [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-constraint-and-restraint) and [this](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/constrain-and-restrain) might be helpful

Comment: Whether someone uses them interchangeably is opinion-based. They mean different things. Nothing prevents someone from using them interchangeably, except perhaps wanting to be well understood.